# Why can not i install an app on Motorola ET1 from Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I just started Xamarin and trying to explore it. I made an app and trying to install it on Motorola ET1 device but i am getting following error:

```
 Detecting installed packages
 Removing old runtime
 Installing shared runtime
 Removing old runtimes
 Installing shared runtime
 Installing platform framework
 Removing previous version of application
 Installing application on device
 Synchronizing assemblies
 Deployment failed because the FastDev assembly directory could not be created.
 Deployment failed. FastDev directory creation failed.
```

I installed the same app on my Galaxy S3 and it worked fine there. I am using mac for development. I googled and found that disabling fast development helps but i could not find where to disable that in Xamarin Studio on mac. Why can not i install this app on Motorola ET1. And how can i do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling Fast assembly deployment in Build/Android Build/Packaging solved my problem.

Comment: It works for me too. but what is really this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Just simply follows these steps for Xamarin Studio:-

1. Go to Project option in menu bar and select last option i.e. YourProjectName.AndroidOption
2. Select Android Build Option in Build Catagory
3. Select Package tab and uncheck the 'Fast Assembly Option' and click on Ok
4. Now, you can Deploye your project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Development USB Debugging (Settings -> Application Settings-> USB Debugging) and also to be able to use Unknown Sources?

Hope this helps,James

Comment: USB Debugging is enabled. I installed an android app using eclipse on Motorola ET1 and it worked fine. It means there is something wrong with Xamarin. How can i disable fast development in Xamarin Studio? I can not find any option like fast development in Xamarin Studio.